# How to get email (default IM) of a google talk chat client instead of public IM

Tags: java, android, xmpp, google-talk

Currently I'm developing a XMPP Google talk chat application. The app is working fine and by analyzing incoming packets(messages) from a specific chat client, I get the username(email) of the sender as "xxx@public.talk.google.com". In my case I want to get the email of the sender instead of public gtalk ID("xxx@public.talk.google.com"). Can I get the email from the public ID? Or a google API to convert it?

Answer (score 1):

These contacts are people who have added you on Google+ with permission to IM you, but not with permission to see your email address, so what you're trying to do is impossible.

Comment: how to add permissions to see my email as username?